# Grover’s algorithm

Tags: grovers-algorithm

According to some references ([Lectures on Quantum Computation at Carnegie Mellon School of Computer Science](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~odonnell/quantum15/lecture04.pdf)) Grover’s algorithm uses only  O($\sqrt{N}\ln {N}$) gates.

Using this to calculate desired hash (such as you have in Bitcoin) will require, as I interpret the above - $256\times{2^{128}}$ gates.
Is this correct interpretation?

Comment: Could you please add more details how you come to the number? I think I cannot give you an answer to your question but I am just courious and I feel that more details would help to somebody who is able to answer the question.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "calculate a desired hash"? Grover's algorithm is designed for unstructured search. Also, it's an example of an oracle algorithm. So, it sort of needs to know what it's looking for

Comment: Grover algorithm reduced the number of oracle calls by its square root, not the number of gates.

Comment: @Martin The link provides details and proofs and I just quoted from the article/lecture

Comment: @TWal you might take advantage of a structured search (I assume it could be faster and more efficient). I wonder if we could take a piece of data and organize it to allow for an efficient search to derive a desired hash -  as example use the bitcoin ounce as a parameter.

Comment: @czwang I used the article (and their claim is supported by a gate diagram). It seems you know more about it - I wonder if you could provide insight into the number of gates as translated from the oracle calls and how many qubits are required?

Answer (score 1):

The $O(N)$ notation does not mean what you're interpretting it to mean. All it means is that as $N$ grows, the running time scales roughly linearly in $N$. But there are constants that are suppressed ($O(N)$ could mean $10^9N$ or $10^{-9}N$) and also ignores all terms in a summation that could grow more slowly, such as $N^{0.95}$ (even if they could dominate at small sizes). It is often not trivial to work out the exact number of gates required for an algorithm, and you certainly need to know a lot more details of the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I still wonder what is the number of gates - the diagram presented in the article depicts the "number of gates". So still not clear - how many gates required to generate a specific Hash from a given Bitcoing Block - finding the ounce that generate such Hash.